# How listing and verbatim do to escape special character?

Tags: listings, verbatim, catcodes, detokenize

I use one macro to display text using `texttt` style. For the moment this macro is very basic. For example, if I want to use the character `_`, its catcode must be changed.

Is there a clever way to escape all the special characters like `listing` and `verbatim` do ? Can `detokenize` be helpfull ?

```
% Sources : 
%   * http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/forcer-le-retour-a-la-ligne-dans-texttt-t13246.html#p127511
%   * http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33465/changing-the-catcode-of-in-one-command

\documentclass{article}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand\breakabletexttt[1]{%
        \begingroup\ttfamily
        \scantokens{\catcode`\_12\makeatletter\breakable@texttt#1\@nil}%
        \endgroup%
    }
    \def\@gobble@fi#1\fi{\fi#1}
    \def\breakable@texttt#1#2\@nil{%
        #1\hspace{0pt plus 0.1pt minus 0.1pt}%
        \ifx\relax#2\relax
        \else
            \@gobble@fi\breakable@texttt#2\@nil
        \fi
    }
    \makeatother


\begin{document}

\breakabletexttt{rangerangerangerange_rangerangerange_rangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerange}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps read [Why doesn’t verbatim work within ...?](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin) and use [`verbdef`](http://ctan.org/pkg/verbdef). Or, if you want breakable monospaced fonts, consider [`url`](http://ctan.org/pkg/url).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you change the catcode first and then read the argument. Direct after reading the argument you can close the group and end the temporary catcode change:

```
\newcommand\breakabletexttt{%
    \begingroup
    \catcode`\_=12
    \@breabletexttt
}
\newcommand\@breabletexttt#1{%
    \endgroup
    % do something with #1 which now contains `_' with catcode 12
    % even if that catcode is now different again
}
```

Normally you should keep the scope of a catcode change to a minimum. Here you might keep the group open as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\breakabletexttt{%
    \begingroup
    \catcode`\_=12
    \@breakabletexttt
}
\newcommand\@breakabletexttt[1]{%
    \ttfamily
    \breakable@texttt#1\@nil%
    \endgroup%
}
\def\@gobble@fi#1\fi{\fi#1}
\def\breakable@texttt#1#2\@nil{%
    #1\hspace{0pt plus 0.1pt minus 0.1pt}%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax
    \else
        \@gobble@fi\breakable@texttt#2\@nil
    \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\breakabletexttt{rangerangerangerange_rangerangerange_rangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerangerange}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The code given by me works. My problem is to find one clever way to escape special characters like `_`, `$`,...

Comment: The way I showed you is basically the normal way to handle verbatim. You don't need to use `\scantokens`. If you want other characters as well, simply change also their catcodes. There would be `\collectverb` from my `newverbs` package, but that also turn macros into verbatim.

Answer (score 3):

`\verb` and `verbatim` use the list stored in `\dospecials`. The most complicated part in their definition is how to end them which is rather tricky as `\` and `}` no longer work. In simple cases you can use simply another char like `]` as end of group:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
{%a new endgroup char:
\catcode`\]=2
\makeatletter\let\do\@makeother \dospecials
_#{}\abc %
] %endgroup

\end{document}
```

`listings` as far as I know quite brutally resets allmost all catcodes at the start.