# Test equality between number of the current page and the one of one reference indicated

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, page-numbering, varioref, xifthen

In the following code, I have one problem with the test `\ifthenelse{\equal{\pageref{#1}}{\thepage}}{...}{...}`. Why doesn't this detect the equality hoped if the reference is in the same page where it is used and defined ?

```
% Sources : 
%   * http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35095/special-footnotes-for-url/35097#35097
%   * http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/how-to-reference-different-places-to-the-same-footnote
%   * http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/forcer-le-retour-a-la-ligne-dans-texttt-t13246.html#p127511
%   * http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33465/changing-the-catcode-of-in-one-command

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{manyfoot}
    \usepackage{xifthen}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{varioref}

% Cosmetic
    \hypersetup{urlcolor=blue}
    \definecolor{urlColor}{named}{DarkRed}

    \newcommand{\urlText}[2][0]{%
        \textcolor{urlColor}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}{%
                \textbf{#2}%
            }{%
                #2%
            }%
        }%
    }

% Special footnote
    \newfootnote{Url}

    \newcounter{footnoteUrl}
    \newcommand{\footnoteUrl}{%
%       \renewcommand\thefootnoteUrl{\Alph{footnoteUrl}}
        \stepcounter{footnoteUrl}%
        \Footnotemark{\urlText{\#\thefootnoteUrl}}\FootnotetextUrl{}%
    }

% New url
    \newcommand{\newUrl}[2][0]{%
        \urlText{http://link/}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}{%
            \footnoteUrl{\, \url{#2}}%
        }{%
            \footnoteUrl{\,\label{#1} \url{#2}}%
        }%
    }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% THE PROBLEM IS HERE... %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Old url
    \newcommand{\oldUrl}[1]{%
        \urlText{http://link/\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\pageref{#1}}{\thepage}}{}{%
            \urlText[1]{(cf.\,page\,\pageref{#1})}%
        }%
    }

    \usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

Let's try to indicate one URL \newUrl[linkGoogle]{http://www.google.fr/}
and another \newUrl{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}.
Let's try to indicate one old URL \oldUrl{linkGoogle}.
and one more \newUrl{http://tug.org/texlive/pkginstall.html}
and another \newUrl[ctan]{http://www.ctan.org/}
 and then the same \oldUrl{ctan}.
I would like to indicate something \footnote{... but here !}.

\lipsum

Just only old URLS \oldUrl{linkGoogle} and \oldUrl{ctan}.
I would like to indicate something \footnote{... but here !}.
\lipsum

Just only old URLS \oldUrl{linkGoogle} and \oldUrl{ctan}.
I would like to indicate something \footnote{... but here !}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use the **bigfoot** package that cooperates with **hyperref**, while **manyfoot** doesn't.

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4180/how-to-use-pagereffoo-as-a-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `hyperref`, your `\pageref` is not just a number, but a link.  Thus it cannot be equal to `\thepage`.

Fortunately, `varioref` package provides the command `\vrefpagenum`, which assigns to its first argument (a macro!) the page label generated by the second argument.

This works for me:

```
\newcommand{\oldUrl}[1]{%
  \vrefpagenum{\urlpage}{#1}%
    \urlText{http://link/\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\urlpage}{\thepage}}{}{%
        \urlText[1]{(cf.\,page\,\pageref{#1})}%
    }%
}
```

UPDATE: Note the important caveat about page number in the answer by Gonzalo Medina

Answer (score 8):

You can use the commands provided by the [`refcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount) package; from the documentation:

> References are not numbers, however they often store numerical data
>   such as section or page numbers. `\ref` or `\pageref` cannot be used for
>   counter assignments or calculations because they are not expandable,
>   generate warnings, or can even be links, The package provides
>   expandable macros to extract the data from references.

So, you could say something like

```
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand{\oldUrl}[1]{%
    \urlText{http://link/\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\thepage}}{}{%
        \urlText[1]{(cf.\,page\,\pageref{#1})}%
    }%
}
```

Also, due to the asynchronous page building mechanism, it's not completely safe to rely on `\thepage`. A standard trick is to use a \label and then invoke \pageref for this label, so you could use something like

```
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{sp}
    \newcommand{\oldUrl}[1]{%
        \stepcounter{sp}\label{sp-\thesp}%
        \urlText{http://link/\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\getpagerefnumber{sp-\thesp}}}{}{%
            \urlText[1]{(cf.\,page\,\pageref{#1})}%
        }%
    }
```

Comment: Why `\protect`? AFAIR, the LaTeX manual says never to put `\protect` in front of `\value`.

Comment: @egreg: right; Lamport says that `\value` is robust and must never be preceded by a `\protect` command. When I was writing my answer I didn't use initially `\protect` and got the error `! You can't use `\relax' after \the.
<recently read> \c@abspage`; I decided then to \protect \value, and didn't get any errors, so I posted my answer; now, however, that you have pointed this issue out, I see that my answer doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @egreg: while I try to solve the `abspage` issue, I've edited my answer with the usual `\label`, `\pageref` trick.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Thanks but I've tried your solution with my code without success... :-(