# \autoref, page reference only if needed (in case of different page number)

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I would like to build a macro `\myautoref{eq:a}`, that

1. if the link and the linked object are on the same page produces `\autoref{eq:a}`
2. if the link and the linked object are on **different** pages produces `\autoref{eq:a} on \autopageref{eq:a}`

In my example below that would mean that the page reference appears only after the reference on page 1.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[unicode,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\autoref{eq:a} on \autopageref{eq:a}

\pagebreak

\autoref{eq:a} on \autopageref{eq:a}

\begin{gather}\label{eq:a}
a
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer based on [Test equality between number of the current page and the one of one reference indicated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35105/test-equality-between-number-of-the-current-page-and-the-one-of-one-reference-in)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[unicode,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{sp}
\newcommand{\myautoref}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{sp}\label{sp-\thesp}%
    \autoref{#1}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\getpagerefnumber{sp-\thesp}}}{}{%
        on \autopageref{#1}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\myautoref{eq:a}

\pagebreak

\myautoref{eq:a}

\begin{gather}\label{eq:a}
  a
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, there is a minor problem: if the "on page" is not needed a space is added(add a dor after myautoref to see it); from your code I can not understand why, its probably some latex trick. (I use xifthen instead of ifthen, but that seams not to make a difference)

Comment: I found the solution: after `\autoref{#1}` a `%` is neeeded: `\autoref{#1}%`

Comment: I just updated the solution to remove the space after \autoref

Answer (score 2):

The functionality you're looking may be obtained in a straightforward fashion by loading the `varioref`, `hyperref`, and `cleveref` packages -- in this order.

Then, `\vref{eq:1}` produces

- `equation (1)` if the cross-referencing call-out (produced by `\vref`) and the object being cross-referenced (here, an equation numbered `(1)`) are both on the *same page*;
- `equation (1) on the facing page` if the document employs a two-sided layout -- as is the case for the `book` document class -- and if the call-out and the equation are located *on facing pages*;
- either `equation (1) on the following page` or `equation (1) on the preceding page` if the *page numbers differ by exactly 1* and *and* aren't placed on facing pages;
- `equation (1) on page [x]` if the page numbers of the cross-reference and equation *differ by 2 or more*.

This setup is easily adapted to non-English languages. E.g., if `ngerman` is specified as a document class option and if the `babel` package is loaded as well, `\vref{eq:1}` will automatically produce "Gleichung (1) auf der vorherigen Seite" instead of "equation (1) on the preceding page".

An MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\vref{eq:a}

\clearpage
\vref{eq:a}

\clearpage
\vref{eq:a}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:a} a \end{equation}

\clearpage
\vref{eq:a}

\clearpage
\vref{eq:a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the answer doesn't use the `\autoref` macro of the `hyperref` package. Instead, it uses the `\vref` package of the `varioref` package. In the code above, `hyperref` is loaded mainly to make the cross-references into hyperlinks. A separate remark: The `cleveref` package is loaded above with the option `nameinlink` so that the output of `\vref` mimics that of `\autoref`; if you don't like this effect, just omit the option `nameinlink`.

Comment: Thank, you. I would start now, I would probably use this solution, but after more than 1000 page I need to minimize the refactoring.