# How to use multiple URLs for one bibtex reference?

Tags: bibtex, urls

I have used this BibTeX reference in my work

```
@Misc{oai:CiteSeerPSU:562256,
  title =   "Gerris: {A} Tree-Based Adaptive Solver For The
         Incompressible Euler Equations In Complex Geometries",
  author =  "St Ephane Popinet",
  year =    "2002",
  month =   sep # "~08",
  abstract =    "An adaptive mesh projection method for the
         time-dependent incompressible Euler equations is
         presented. The domain is spatially discretised using
         quad/octrees and a multilevel Poisson solver is used to
         obtain the pressure. Complex solid boundaries are
         represented using a volume-of-fluid approach.
         Second-order convergence in space and time is
         demonstrated on regular, statically and dynamically
         refined grids. The quad/octree discretisation proves to
         be very flexible and allows accurate and efficient
         tracking of flow features. The source code of the
         method implementation is freely available.",
  citeseer-references = "oai:CiteSeerPSU:500259; oai:CiteSeerPSU:27423;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:16254; oai:CiteSeerPSU:395363;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:436925; oai:CiteSeerPSU:90307;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:391348; oai:CiteSeerPSU:137987;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:442611; oai:CiteSeerPSU:44620;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:150038; oai:CiteSeerPSU:433875;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:441861; oai:CiteSeerPSU:526586",
  bibsource =   "OAI-PMH server at cs1.ist.psu.edu",
  language =    "en",
  oai =     "oai:CiteSeerPSU:562256",
  rights =  "unrestricted",
  URL =     "http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/562256.html;
         http://gfs.sf.net/gerris.pdf",
}
```

, but in the bibliography, instead of getting two separate links two the two urls, I get both urls merged into one link like this: http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/562256.html;http://gfs.sf.net/gerris.pdf. Is there any way in which I can get the two urls separated and to get one link to each ulr? Frankly, I don't know what the best practice is for url linking in the bibliography, but what I have now is quite useless.

Edit: I'm using JabRef, and it modifies the bibtex code on the web page I linked to from

`url = "http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/562256.html; http://gfs.sf.net/gerris.pdf"`

to

`url = {http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/562256.html; http://gfs.sf.net/gerris.pdf}`.

In other words, it removes the quotation signs and inserts curly brackets instead. I don't know, maybe this can cause some problem?

Comment: Without a MWE it's hard to say but I suspect that since hyperref turns the url field into a link automatically, there might be no way to do what you want without major modifications to the bibliography style. Would using something like `note="PDF: \url{http://gfs.sf.net/gerris.pdf}"` be an option?

Comment: You linked pdf can't be open. However it's the best to provide a small picture instead of linking

Comment: @Marco Daniel: I you look at the url you see what I mean; this is how LaTeX formats it. Maybe I shouldn't have converted the text into a link, but this is what LaTeX does so I wanted to do the same thing here.

Comment: @Christian: I solved it by simply remove one of the urls. I figured it doesn't really make sense to have more than one link to the same document, especially if one of them require a login that you maybe don't have.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever I wouldn't call that "solved" but yeah, that way the problem's gone ;)

Comment: How can I mark my own comment as the accepted answer? :P I want to mark this thread as solved.

Comment: Check out the second answer. I think that's the best.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Most bibliography styles format the field `url` direct with the command `\url`.

You can use the field `note` to add unformatted text:

```
 NOTE =     "\url{http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/562256.html} and 
             \url{http://gfs.sf.net/gerris.pdf}",
```

Comment: Most style use a prefix like `URL: ` to format the url field. Simply add it to the note for full camouflage in the output.

Comment: For some documents, the tip by @ojdo is still visually distinguishable from "real" URL entries. At least in my case, I was able to make the camouflage even more perfect with `\textsc{url:}`.

Comment: For reference managers like Mendeley, this is a lot of manual work to change url to note.

Answer (score 12):

you can modify the `\url` command with a redefinition to take two urls into account:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test3.bib}
@Misc{oai:CiteSeerPSU:562256,
  title =   "Gerris: {A} Tree-Based Adaptive Solver For The
         Incompressible Euler Equations In Complex Geometries",
  author =  "St Ephane Popinet",
  year =    "2002",
  month =   sep # "~08",
  abstract =    "An adaptive mesh projection method for the
         time-dependent incompressible Euler equations is
         presented. The domain is spatially discretised using
         quad/octrees and a multilevel Poisson solver is used to
         obtain the pressure. Complex solid boundaries are
         represented using a volume-of-fluid approach.
         Second-order convergence in space and time is
         demonstrated on regular, statically and dynamically
         refined grids. The quad/octree discretisation proves to
         be very flexible and allows accurate and efficient
         tracking of flow features. The source code of the
         method implementation is freely available.",
  citeseer-references = "oai:CiteSeerPSU:500259; oai:CiteSeerPSU:27423;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:16254; oai:CiteSeerPSU:395363;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:436925; oai:CiteSeerPSU:90307;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:391348; oai:CiteSeerPSU:137987;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:442611; oai:CiteSeerPSU:44620;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:150038; oai:CiteSeerPSU:433875;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:441861; oai:CiteSeerPSU:526586",
  bibsource =   "OAI-PMH server at cs1.ist.psu.edu",
  language =    "en",
  oai =     "oai:CiteSeerPSU:562256",
  rights =  "unrestricted",
  URL =     "http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/562256.html;
         http://gfs.sf.net/gerris.pdf",
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{test3.bib}
\let\URL\url
\makeatletter
\def\url#1{\@URL#1;;\@nil}
\def\@URL#1;#2;#3\@nil{%
  \URL{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else; \URL{#2}\fi}
\makeatother
%url = {http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/562256.html; http://gfs.sf.net/gerris.pdf}

\begin{document}

foo\cite{oai:CiteSeerPSU:562256}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you did here! What does url contain after the line `\addbibresource{test3.bib}`? What does it contain if there are more than one reference? And what do the two macros do?

Comment: I saved the old definition of `\url` as `\URL` and then redefined `\url` to be able to read two urls devided by a `;`

Comment: Will this method be the same even if you use the `hyperref` package and not the `url` package?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever: Yes, but the urls must be in _one_ line

Comment: How can I do this if my urls were separated by a space, as in `url = {http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/562256.html http://gfs.sf.net/gerris.pdf}`? Is there a way to do this for 4 URLs, or even N URLs?

Answer (score 5):

Won't let me comment on Herbert's answer. So based on his answer:

- When you copy this into your own code, make sure you place it *after* you include packages like `url` or `hyperref`.
- To use spaces instead of semicolons, just replace the semicolons with spaces. This is useful for Mendeley-generated BibTeX files. When two spaces are immediately next to each other, you have to escape one so they don't disappear, i.e. `;;` becomes `\` (a backslash with two spaces around it). Here's a version where I additionally removed the third argument (second space) because it apparently wasn't necessary (?), and so there's no backslash anymore, either.

  ```
  \let\URL\url
  \makeatletter
  \def\url#1{\@URL#1 \@nil}
  \def\@URL#1 #2\@nil{\URL{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax \else; \URL{#2}\fi}
  \makeatother
  ```

  Note that I left the "output semicolon" in there because I think it looks nice. Technically, you can write whatever you like there, including any arbitrary commands.
- To extend it to `N` URLs, you have to call the macro recursively with the second argument (which will contain the remaining `N-1` space-separated URLs). For some reason, an additional `\relax` is necessary to make it work, found this out by accident:

  ```
  \let\URL\url
  \makeatletter
  \def\url#1{\@URL#1 \@nil}
  \def\@URL#1 #2\@nil{\URL{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax \else; \url{#2\relax}\fi}
  \makeatother
  ```
- To handle urls with the percent sign `%` and with the hash sign `#` correctly, glean some inspiration from [Changing the catcode of _ in one command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33478/41245) and further adjust the definitions as follows:

  ```
  \let\URL\url
  \makeatletter
  \def\url{\begingroup \catcode`\%=12\catcode`\#=12\relax\printurl}
  \def\printurl#1{\@URL#1 \@nil\endgroup}
  \def\@URL#1 #2\@nil{\URL{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax \else; \url{#2\relax}\fi}
  \makeatother
  ```

Comment: Doesn't work with Mendeley, unfortunately, as biblatex converts the space to "%20" before it reaches the code.

Answer (score 2):

To make this work with Mendeley and avoid the issue that biblatex converts the space separator between urls to "%20" before it reaches the code, use the following command to redefine the url bibmacro to use urlraw instead of url.

```
\renewbibmacro*{url}{\printfield[url]{urlraw}}

\let\URL\url
\makeatletter
\def\url{\begingroup \catcode`\%=12\catcode`\#=12\relax\printurl}
\def\printurl#1{\@URL#1 \@nil\endgroup}
\def\@URL#1 #2\@nil{\URL{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax \else; \url{#2\relax}\fi}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

About @Marco Daniel's `note` answer, I'd advice using `addendum` rather than  `note` to ensure URL are placed at the end of the entry, as are `URL` fields. Indeed, `note` is printed in the middle of the entry in some styles.

Using `note`:
[image: bib entry print using note field: URLs are not at the end of the entry in some style]

Using `addendum`:

[image: bib entry print using addendum field: URLs are always at the end of the entry]

Entry code:

```
@book{Roland_Gautier,
    address = {Tours},
    author = {Gautier, Léon},
    keywords = {ling},
    publisher = {Alfred Mame et Fils},
    title = {La Chanson de Roland},
    year = {1872},
    Addendum = {\textsc{url} : \url{https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k102947j} (t. \textsc{i}), \url{https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k102948x} (t. \textsc{ii})},
    volumes = {2}
    }
```