# More than one URL per Mendeley reference

Tags: bibliographies, urls

Mendeley can handle multiple URLs for each reference. When exporting to Bibtex it separates the URLs with spaces. This causes a `%20` and broken links in the output.

I import references into Sharelatex from Mendeley, so I don't want to fix this manually. How can I fix the reference URL?

bibliography.bib:

```
@misc{MyRef,
    title = {A paper},
    url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com https://www.sharelatex.com/}
}
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Reference \cite{MyRef}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57865.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to fix this manually"? Can you change the field `url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com https://www.sharelatex.com/}` to `note = {\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com} and \url{https://www.sharelatex.com/}}`?

Comment: @javadr The mentioned link does not solve the problem in this question.

Comment: @Mico Imagine you have 100 references with multiple URLs in Mendeley. Who would go and manually change every \url in these 100 references to \note?

Comment: @Curious - Are you suggesting that Mendeley tends to create a host of truly bizarre and intractable problems and hence should be avoided? :-)

Comment: @Mico I am not suggesting that, but thinking towards that :) No solution to a genuine problem even after 3 years. What does it lead you to think?

Comment: @Curious - If Mendeley keeps pumping out guaranteed-to-fail bad data such as `url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com https://www.sharelatex.com/}`, it's definitely Mendeley's job, and not the job of individual users, to provide a fix. Aside: I do *not* use Mendeley for my own working papers and publications, and I wouldn't advise anyone to rely on Mendeley for anything but the most inconsequential experiments.