# Multiple URLs in Mendeley

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, cross-referencing, multiple-citations, mendeley

**Motivation**

It is often the case that I save multiple urls for the same Mendeley reference, for example, link to a paper and another link to its video, so that I can easily find just by clicking on it from Mendeley.
Also I want that I have all these links in the draft/presentation so that the readers can do the same.

But I couldn't figure out a nice *automated* way to do it. Of course, one way is to change `url` to `note` but there are various problems:

1. I don't find `note` in the available fields for most commonly used document types (conference proceedings, journal article and generic) in Mendeley.
2. I cannot make use of the simple functionality of click to open in Mendeley
3. It is indeed a lot of manual effort if I try to change each `url` to `note`

Hence, the solutions proposed in [How to use multiple URLs for one bibtex reference?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57865/how-to-use-multiple-urls-for-one-bibtex-reference) are not useful. For instance, doing the following does not help. Any *automated* way of handling this would be great.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test3.bib}
@Misc{oai:CiteSeerPSU:562256,
  title =   "Gerris: {A} Tree-Based Adaptive Solver For The
         Incompressible Euler Equations In Complex Geometries",
  author =  "St Ephane Popinet",
  year =    "2002",
  month =   sep # "~08",
  abstract =    "An adaptive mesh projection method for the
         time-dependent incompressible Euler equations is
         presented. The domain is spatially discretised using
         quad/octrees and a multilevel Poisson solver is used to
         obtain the pressure. Complex solid boundaries are
         represented using a volume-of-fluid approach.
         Second-order convergence in space and time is
         demonstrated on regular, statically and dynamically
         refined grids. The quad/octree discretisation proves to
         be very flexible and allows accurate and efficient
         tracking of flow features. The source code of the
         method implementation is freely available.",
  citeseer-references = "oai:CiteSeerPSU:500259; oai:CiteSeerPSU:27423;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:16254; oai:CiteSeerPSU:395363;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:436925; oai:CiteSeerPSU:90307;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:391348; oai:CiteSeerPSU:137987;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:442611; oai:CiteSeerPSU:44620;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:150038; oai:CiteSeerPSU:433875;
         oai:CiteSeerPSU:441861; oai:CiteSeerPSU:526586",
  bibsource =   "OAI-PMH server at cs1.ist.psu.edu",
  language =    "en",
  oai =     "oai:CiteSeerPSU:562256",
  rights =  "unrestricted",
  URL =     "http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/562256.html http://gfs.sf.net/gerris.pdf http://gfs.sf.net/new.pdf",
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{test3.bib}
\let\URL\url
\makeatletter
\def\url#1{\@URL#1 \@nil}
\def\@URL#1 #2\@nil{\URL{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax \else; \url{#2\relax}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

foo\cite{oai:CiteSeerPSU:562256}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about the requirements for the input? Do you insist on inputting all URLs into the same field separated with spaces? Can you guarantee that your URLs will never contains spaces themselves?

Comment: @moewe I am not sure what exactly do you mean by the input. Mendeley formats the multiple URLs via space between them when exported as a bib file. Yes, I would like to have all URLs into the same field, so that there is no manual work involved. I think this is very often the case for me that my URLs do not contain a space: At least that would be one step towards the solution to this problem.

Comment: In this case I mean the `.bib` file (as input to `biblatex`/Biber). So you are limited by Mendeley's export and need a solution that parses the list of URLs as a space-separated list in the `url` field? Can you guarantee that the URLs don't contain spaces? (If not, how should `biblatex` be able to tell if a space belongs to the URL or separates two URLs?)

Comment: @moewe Yes, I am limited by the Mendeley's exported `.bib` file. I tried it now and found that Mendeley keeps the spaces within URLs as it is. But let's assume that URLs don't contain spaces.