# 12 catcode for UNDERSCORE and character printed

Tags: latex3, catcodes

Does a `LaTeX3` version of the following code could be simpler? I understand the logic, but I dislike the code...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}

% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33478/6880
\def\test{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\_=12\relax
  \ttest}
\def\ttest#1{%
  \color{red}\fbox{#1}%
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

The smallest \test{txt_example} in the world.

\end{document}
```

Another question. Is there a way to see an underscore because I have the following output?

[image]

Comment: In OT1 encoded fonts, the slot for `_` is taken by the dot accent (unless you use `\ttfamily`).

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. I will use `\ttfamily`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OT1 encoded fonts, the slot for `_` is taken by the dot accent, unless you use `\ttfamily`. Use T1.

Is there a simpler version? Yes, there is.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{v}{%
  \fbox{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\textcolor{red}{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

The smallest \test{txt_example} in the world.

\end{document}
```

The `v` argument specifier means “collect the argument verbatim”.

[image]

With `\ttfamily` instead of `\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont` you'd get

[image]

Of course you don't need to select the encoding if you have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in your document preamble, which is essentially mandatory for documents in (continental) European languages, including French.

Comment: Very instructive. I understand the TeX version, but definitely LaTeX3 wins here. Thanks for all.