# How to deal with very long lstinline-phrases like long class names?

Tags: listings, line-breaking, hyphenation

According to this Question:

[How to deal with very long lines that do not contain spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33459/listing-how-to-deal-with-very-long-lines-that-do-not-contain-spaces)

My problem is that my `\lstinline`-phrases does not contain any special character like "-". In my lstlinlines there are very long class name like `ThisIsAVeryLongExampleClassNameAndItHasNoLineBreak`. The problem that results from those class names are overfull boxes.

Does anyone knows an approach how to set conditional line breaking marks. (Like `\-` in normal text).

Comment: I don't think that from programmation point of view it is a good idea to use too long name.

Comment: I know, but the models are given, and so I have no other choice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or, to make things fully automatic (in your case):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinline[
  literate={A}{A}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {B}{B}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {C}{C}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {D}{D}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {E}{E}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {F}{F}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {G}{G}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {H}{H}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {I}{I}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {J}{J}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {K}{K}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {L}{L}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {M}{M}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {N}{N}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {O}{O}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {P}{P}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {Q}{Q}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {R}{R}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {S}{S}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {T}{T}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {U}{U}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {V}{V}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {W}{W}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {X}{X}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {Y}{Y}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
           {Z}{Z}{1\discretionary{}{}{}}
!ThisIsAVeryLongExampleClassNameAndItHasNoLineBreakThisIsAVeryLongExampleClassNameAndItHasNoLineBreakThisIsAVeryLongExampleClassNameAndItHasNoLineBreakThisIsAVeryLongExampleClassNameAndItHasNoLineBreakThisIsAVeryLongExampleClassNameAndItHasNoLineBreak!
```

\end{document}

Obviously, this should be put in a style...

(To get `-` at the end of the line, use `\discretionary{-}{}{}`. 26 times :-)

Comment: The drawback with this method is that keywords can't use capital letters. I think that the better solution is the one using ``\-``.

Comment: I guess nothing is wrong with using both methods. For the user, it is trivial to decide which is better, at least in the context of inline-listings.

Comment: And, being (also) a `python`ist, I'd make myself another method for breaking at `_`.

Comment: How do you do ? Python does the job for you ? I like to use Python but I also do my best to automatically produce not too ugly LaTeX code (so as to obtain LaTeX codes that can be read by one human as far as it is possible).

Comment: I expressed myself badly... Python and TeX are (mostly) separate worlds in my life. But both are beautiful ;-)

Answer (score 9):

The cool trick from the question you have cited can be used to define a conditional line break:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
Bla bla blabla blabla bla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla
bla blabla bla blablablabla bla
\lstinline[literate={\\\-}{}{0\discretionary{-}{}{}}]!ThisIsAVeryLong\-Example\-ClassNameAndItHasNoLineBreak!
bla blabla blabla blabla bla
\end{document}
```

P.S. I guess the `\\` as the second arg of `\discretionary` in the cited question was as mistake? Anyway, the above works for me.

Comment: this also works fine in a style

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck tonight following these two steps:

1. Break the name explicitly: `\lstinline{ThisIsAVeryLongExampleClassName}\lstinline{AndItHasNoLineBreak}`
2. Ensure your preceding `lstset` has `breaklines=true` (or just `breaklines` actually).