# Preventing line break at the start of a long name in `\lstinline`

Tags: listings, line-breaking, hyphenation

This question has developed from [How to deal with very long lstinline-phrases like long class names?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69346/how-to-deal-with-very-long-lstinline-phrases-like-long-class-names).

That question is about line breaking inside a `\lstinline` phrase. I have provided an answer which automatically hyphenates on capital letters, and then, in a comment, I realized it could sometimes be useful to have automatic hyphenation on underscores `_` as well.

I managed to implement this, but one glitch remains: I would like to prevent automatic `_`-hyphenation at the start of the name (in Python, for example, this is common situation, as by convention, internal names start with an underscore (or two)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lstdoc}
\lstMakeShortInline[literate={\_}{\_}{1\discretionary{\_}{}{}}]|

\begin{document}
\textbf{Good line break:} in this paragraph the line break in the
python's variable |a_python_style_name| is good!

\textbf{Bad line break:} the internal variable |_internal_python_name|
is not hyphenated very nicely in this paragraph.
\end{document}
```

[image: A good and a bad line-break in <code>\listinline</code>]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Circumvent the `\discretionary` insertion by inserting something else just for the start. Here are some options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=8cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lstdoc}
\lstset{mathescape=true}
\lstMakeShortInline[literate={\_}{\_}{1\discretionary{\_}{}{}} {~}{\_}{1}]|
\newcommand{\preunderscore}{\_}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Good line break:} in this paragraph the line break in the
python's variable |a_python_style_name| is good!

\textbf{Bad line break:} the internal variable |_internal_python_name|\par
|_internal_python_name|

\textbf{Bad line break:} the internal variable |~internal_python_name|\par
|~internal_python_name|

\textbf{Bad line break:} the internal variable |$\preunderscore$internal_python_name|\par
|$\preunderscore$internal_python_name|
\end{document}
```

With `mathescape` you can insert a macro instead of a `literate` replacement for `_`. Alternatively, use a different `literate` character for the start. There are differences in spacing.