# listings breaklines not working

Tags: listings, line-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with very long lines that do not contain spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33459/how-to-deal-with-very-long-lines-that-do-not-contain-spaces)

When I use the listings package with breaklines, it doesn't seem to break lines properly if there is no whitespace. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines=true, breakatwhitespace=false}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
blah blah
blah blah
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This gets rendered like this:

[image]

Is there some way to get long lines like this to break? I thought setting breakatwhitespace to false would fix this.