# "Issue with Line Breaks in URLs within lstlisting Environment

Tags: listings, urls

The line breaks within lstlisting environments do not function properly for URLs, even though `breaklines` and `breakatwhitespace` are both set to true. The URLs are not being broken, and the text exceeds the boundary of the page.

Could someone please assist me in resolving this issue? I have already set `breaklines` and `breakatwhitespace` to true, but URLs within lstlisting environments are not being properly broken across lines, causing the text to extend beyond the page margins. You can see the problem in this screenshot.

[image]

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{black}\small,
    frame=tb,
    extendedchars=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    breaklines=true,
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20!white},
    breakautoindent=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Test this part of the file: breaking line shouldn't be a problem
in the normal text. But as soon as I have a Listing with a long
text (e.g. token or a hash) then it doesn't work properly. What
also doesn't work is when I'm having a \ texttt in the end of the
line like \texttt{ThisExampleForLongTextWhichDoesNotBreakeAtTheEndOfTheLine}

\begin{lstlisting}
GET https://192.168.178.73:8443/v1/devices/ HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjEwOWMwNTA5MDYzYTk3YmFkMGE2ZWEzMmM3MmE3NmExMzg4NWFkOWRiMmM5OWY0ZmNiNDJiZGEwNQ3OTYwMDcifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhN2ZkMDAyNi01NTc5LTQ4ZTItYjg3MS1hMjA5YWExNjhhYmUiLCJ0eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiYXVkIjoiaG9tZXNtYXJ0LmxvY2FsIiwic3ViIjoiZTQwNTUwMjYtY2JkMC00MjgyLWE0NmEtZWRhOTI5OTE2Zjk1IiwiaWF0IjoxNjgyMDMDc1LCJleHAiOjE5OT2NTQwNzV9.dhX3QfPqVYklVYGWWskvvpi81tVl6k7dZEJFbGNfOncnq2ATnkzR1HZsdFSNbirsu59k2xv2LKdwq5kR_HxEA
Host: 192.168.178.73:8443
Connection: Keep-Alive
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please provide an example document, don't make people debug an image

Comment: What happens if you delete `breakatwhitespace=true`? Based on your screenshot, it seems that the line is broken at the space between GET and the url because of `breakatwhitespace`. Because the line is already "broken" at the space, listings doesn't perform further breaks within the url.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle of course, here an example [https://www.overleaf.com/read/zyvfnynrgvxf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/zyvfnynrgvxf)

Comment: Just to let you know, it's best to put the code inside your question so that it's self-contained, rather than linking to Overleaf. Perhaps [this past answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33464) may help to solve your problem?

Comment: please don't use external links,

Comment: @gz839918 no, unfortunately this didn't solve the problem